# Is there a way to render html content in tooltip of icon/span in angular 7

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, tooltip, kendo-tooltip

Is there a way to render Html content in the tooltip of icon/span in angular 7

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recently just found out, you can use the 'tooltiptemplate' with '[filter="*"]'
just have a look at this [stackblitz-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmhf6a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)